# DS1302 RTC board weird outputs on Arduino's Serial monitor

Tags: arduino, serial-port, real-time-clock

I have a DS1302 RTC board (Waveshare) connected to an Arduino uno.

I'm printing time to Arduino's Serial Monitor but I get weird numbers/characters, and after 2-4 seconds it stops printing.

**Wiring:**

Vcc -> 5v

GND -> GND

I/O (MISO) -> Pin 12

SCLK -> Pin 13

CE (CS) -> Pin 10

**Library used:** VirtuabotixRTC library.

**Things I've tried so far:**

I tried a second DS1302 RTC board.

I tried a different Arduino board.

I tried changing the jumper wires.

I tried different baud rates.

**Code:**

```
#include <virtuabotixRTC.h>

virtuabotixRTC myRTC(7,8,9);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  //  myRTC.setDS1302Time(30,30,5,5,5,5,2020);
}

void loop() {
  myRTC.updateTime();
  Serial.print(myRTC.hours);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(myRTC.minutes);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(myRTC.seconds);
}
```

**Screenshots:**
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is here any reason that you connect the module to pin 10, 12, and 13, but your sketch is showing `myRTC(7,8,9)`, shouldn't it be `myRTC(13, 12, 10)`?

Comment: It's just a screenshot of a previous test (I tried other pins)

Comment: Whatever, look at the sketch code you posted yourself. it simply not match the description of your connection

Comment: Put a delay(500) in your loop, not to constantly looping. the RTC may not be able to response faster enough.

Comment: Delay doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Chances are you are over-runningthe transmit buffer - add a long delay like 1 second between reads and see if that works better